# Confusion about PDF formula for PPP in Euclidean plane

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-process

I have a Poisson point process (PPP) $\Phi$ with intensity $\lambda_M$ (density in Euclidean plane). If $R_m$ denotes the distance from a reference point, then what does the following equation means? As per my understanding, $r$ is some random variable such that $0\leq r \leq R_m$.

PDF of $R_m$ is given (in the research paper I am reading) by:

(btw, I did not find this formula on the web, and the research article has not shared any reference either. Maybe it is too well known, but not for me)

$$f_{R_m}(r) = 2\pi \lambda_M\ r\ \exp(-\lambda_M\pi\ r^2)$$

Since $\lambda_m$ is the density in the Euclidean plane, should the PDF formula be:

$$f_{R_m}(r) = (\lambda_M\ \pi r^2)^n \exp(-\lambda_M\pi\ r^2)/n!$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this question in this paper titled, "A Tractable Approach to Coverage and Rate in Cellular Networks"

Link: [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6042301)

Summary is attached below as the image

[image]